# How can I change the color of Ubuntu Touch ToolBar?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Here is my situation:

[image: Youtune App]

Does anyone know how to **change colour of the bottom toolbar**?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is not a way to change to color of the bottom toolbar. There is no official way to do it, but there may be a hack to do it.

However, the toolbar at the bottom will be going away, being replaced by toolbar buttons in the header (and search will replace the header title). See [this post](http://design.canonical.com/2014/03/new-apps-header/) on the Canonical design blog for further details.

Comment: You're right, I've checked the related code and the Toolbar component does not expose the internal QObject where the styleItem is defined. Thanks for the design post btw.